# Check to see what else is loaded on Mac OSX

Tags: macos

First of all please forgive me for my ignorance. I'm not sure if this is possible.

I might be playing around and installed a lot of software, tools, databases or servers or services such as macports, php, etc. Over a period of time I might forget what I've put in and there maybe a lot of stuff I dosen't need anymore. Is there any way or Terminal command that allow me to check what is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty much impossible, since you can place applications just about anywhere you like. Additionally, what constitutes an "application" might be debatable — does a two-line shell script count?

---

Regular applications are usually located in `/Applications`, `~/Applications` (for every user).

Widgets are in `~/Library/Widgets` (every user) or `/Library/Widgets`(unusual, system-wide).

Preference Panes are in `/Library/PreferencePanes`(all users) or `~/Library/PreferencePanes` (every user)

These are basically the things you'd install manually.

---

If you installed something using a regular installer, this has been logged to `/Library/Receipts`(installer *Receipts*  and the `InstallHistory.plist` log file).

---

If you're using Homebrew, Fink, or MacPorts Unix package managers, they keep track of what they installed. Look up their documentation.

---

If you installed something manually (QuickLook plugins come to mind), or compiled something yourself, then you're basically out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, everything that is installed via the OS X package installed (.pkg or .mpkg) is tracked in /Library/Receipts/InstallHistory.plist. As far as drag and drop installs, you would have to trawl through the file system to look for those.

You could issue a command such as `find / -type d -name MacOS` which would indicated some sort of bundle in OS X, but the risk there is that you identify frameworks and system files and such.

Comment: Can I edit the InstallHistory.plist manually to remove stuff that I dosen't want anymore?

Comment: I'm not sure what you would hope to accomplish. The .plist file is simply a list of what was installed -- a registry of sorts. Editing it will not remove any software.

Answer (score 0):

Fear not!

```
man hier
```

Will show you where things should be. And where they should not be, such as installed into /Users/Shared, eh Adobe?